# Div clipping when zooming and applying CSS perspective

Tags: html, css, 3d

On this page: https://kopiro.github.io/pika-bulba/, everything works fine until you zoom in the page, and then the road start to disappear.

Everything is made using CSS and perspective, and the road is just a div with a texture that repeats using background-image-repeat-y.

The same problem is actually present in iPhone safari, where the texture doesn't even load.

An interesting things is that `rotateX(90.00000001deg)` instead of `rotateX(90deg)` fixes the issue in Safari

Any idea on what may be causing this?

Repository here: https://github.com/kopiro/pika-bulba

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really cool game, love the work! I'm not certain I can help answer the question, but if I find anything of use I'll be sure to let you know

Comment: It works fine in Windows Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Sanxofonhave you tried to zoom 200% in Chrome?

Comment: The issue is very apparent on Brave (Fedora 39).